# What is the scope of Http.context in Play Framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

Http Context seems to be acting weird in my app. Is it possible for the values stored in Http context to span multiple requests?

I'm on Play Framework version 2.3.6.

Following is the code in my controller:

```
ctx().args.put("version", 1);
```

And following is the way I'm fetching it back:

```
Http.Context.current().args.get("version");
```

Now, base on the request, I set the value of "version" in the context and fetch wherever required. The problem that I'm having right now is that when the request is received for version 2, the context still returns version 1.

Comment: Any piece of code you can share? thanks

Comment: How are you storing the values?

Comment: I've updated my question with code.

Answer (score 2):

You can store only strings and only very limited size And only if the session requests are done from the same browser.  The reason is that nothing in session is stored on the server.

Documentation:

> It’s important to understand that Session and Flash data are not stored by the server but are added to each subsequent HTTP request, using the cookie mechanism. This means that the data size is very limited (up to 4 KB) and that you can only store string values.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaSessionFlash